# In IOS app or SAFARI Browser, anchor tag click is not working properly

Tags: ios, web-applications, safari, anchor

I have created an app with a web view. Multiple anchor tags are used but when I click on them for a particular IOS device (iPhone), I have to click double on that tag. It works fine on Android devices but on iPhones or Safari browsers in mobile mode, it's not.

Give some solution for this

I have removed the hover CSS on the anchor tag for mobile but it still has that problem.

My code is:

```
<style>
  .active_class {
    background-color: #ad0d01!important; 
    color: white!important;
  }
  .border-maroon{
    border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0!important;
  }
  .nav-link .border-maroon{
    color:black!important;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .border-maroon:hover {
      background-color: #ad0d01!important; 
      color:white!important;
    }
  }
</style>
<li class="nav-item" tabindex="0">
  <a href="index.php?page=home" class="nav-link border-maroon <?=$page=='home'?'active_class':''?>">
    <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
    <p>Dashboard</p>
  </a>
</li>
```

I am also using the Bootstrap classes.